# How can I select all the link which have an image child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following to add a _blank target attribute to all my external links

```
$.expr[':'].external = function(obj) {
    return (obj.hostname != location.hostname) && obj.href.startsWith("http");
};

$('a:external').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Now, I would like to do similarly for all links that are parent to images.

```
<a href="..."><img></a>
```

How can I build a selector to target these instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target elements which contain another specific element you can use the [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector) selector:

```js
$('a:has(img)').prop('target', '_blank');
```

Also, just as an aside, the `:external` selector logic can be made more succinct with an arrow function:

```js
$.expr[':'].external = obj => (obj.hostname != location.hostname) && obj.href.startsWith("http");
```